# what is the acceleration parameter in a universe?

Tags: universe

Obtain the value of the acceleration parameter in a universe, including cosmological radiation and constant.
what is the exactly acceleration parameter in a universe means ?
[image]

Comment: Post updated...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deceleration_parameter

Comment: @Fariborz Are you still interested for an answer ?